# Codenvy preview for Angular project

Tags: angular, codenvy

I am trying to preview an angular app from codenvy. As per the instructions, [Codenvy preview docs](https://codenvy.io/docs/user-guide/previews/index.html) I tried creating a command as the following:`cd myproject/public; ng serve`. I used the following command macro `${server.8000}`. This gives me a preview URL but, I navigate to the URL, I get the error that the site cannot be reached.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is still needed. I will add the solution in case someone else is looking for it.

Did you add the macro in the **Preview URL** section of the command? You do not need macros in the `--host` input to your command. Instead you will need to add `--host 0.0.0.0`. You also need to add `--public-host ${server.4200}` otherwise you will get an **Invalid Host header** error.

The full command i used:

```
cd ${current.project.path} && ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --public-host ${server.4200}
```